# Jcarousel chrome issue

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, jcarousel

I have a rather strange issue with JCarousel on chrome and safari. Basically it doesn't load properly and adds to extra items before like this:

```
class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-undefined jcarousel-item-undefined-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal" style="float: left; list-style: none;

class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-NaN jcarousel-item-NaN-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal" style="float: left; list-style: none; " jcarouselindex="NaN"
```

Once this happens i can't scroll left or right, it's just grayed out. The other weird thing is that it only happens on QA environment not on my local so it's really difficult to debug. Any ideas anyone? FYI i did move the call from `document.ready` to `window.load` and made no difference.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should post some code or maybe a link to the page with the problem or a jsfiddle

Comment: found any solution to this? I am getting the same..